# Disable write permission for the user, Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I'll be brief. I need to disable a single user to read and write files on the whole server with Ubuntu, except one file. That is, he can write to the file output.txt, but other directories are closed to him. How it can be implemented without changing the ownership of files on the whole server? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a *chroot login* for this user so that he/she is constrained to a directory.  You could then place `output.txt` in this chroot or if that isn't possible, create a symlink to `output.txt` in the directory.

`openssh` can be configured to chroot your users.  However, that's the easy bit.  The complex bt will be to work out which files (executables, libraries and config files) to place in the chroot so that the user can actually do something useful.

Your best bet is to Google [linux chroot login](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=chroot++login+ssh) as the answer would probably be too long and to task specific to be placed here.